# It was running perfectly; after reinstall windows,update flutter version, it gives me these two error ; but i did mention the correct Compilesdk

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, build

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception. ----------- * Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 156  * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script. > Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.    >

Cannot add task 'generateLockfiles' as a task with that name already exists.  * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. =============================================================================

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 463

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Tried to change compileSDK
multiDeskEnabled true